# MIPS shift left logical

Tags: assembly, mips, sll

What would be another way to write the code below?

```
li $t1, 1      # load 1 in register $t1
sll $t1, $t1, 23    # shift value of 1 to the 24th bit to get 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

I am concerned that this code does not not actually shift 1 to the 24th bit. So what would be another way to write it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `lui $t1, (1<<23) >> 16` or simply `li $t1, 1<<23` should assemble to an LUI that does it with one instruction with no runtime shift.  What makes you think that your code doesn't shift a `1` to bit #23, i.e. the 24th bit counting from the bottom?  Looks fine to me (except inefficient of course for a constant base and count); show debugger output if you think it's wrong.

Comment: Or simply `li $t1, 0x00800000`.  The assembler might convert that to a two instruction sequence, but from a source perspective, it is very readable.

Comment: @ErikEidt But li only loads 16 bits. Isn't 0x00800000 more than 16 bit instruction?

Comment: The assembler might convert that to a two instruction sequence.